# How to stop automatic chrome browser opening on windows xp

Tags: google-chrome, windows-xp

I have a problem.each time my chrome browser is opening many tabs automatically.I need to stop them.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Accounts. Remove (occult) Chrome from auto startup.

Also, you could try using [AutoRuns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

PS: This is a question for the superuser forum.

Comment: i have done as per you before.Here my problem is tabs are opening at any time not only at the start of the chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstall Chrome and Reinstall (if you know Registry , you delete KEY Software/ chrome in Local Machine and current use . Scan virus for your Computer.